# GIS/ArcPy: extracting land use data from a raster and assignig to shapefile polygons

Tags: gis, raster, arcpy

I have two maps for the same area (1) a raster land use map and (2) a shapefile with thousands of sub-watersheds. I am trying to assign the land use type from the raster (map 1) to each of the sub-watershed (map 2) based on the majority rule. I tried spatial join, but the result seems to be wrong. What is the best way of doing it either in ArcMap or through arcpy?

Comment: Can you better describe what "seems wrong" about the results you got? A spatial join would be the first method I try too, so I'd need more details to help troubleshoot.

Comment: My goal is to identify land use with the maximum area in the overlapping area and assign that land use in the shapefile polygon. In spatial join, I used 'INTERSECT' as match option. In the 'Field Map of Join Features' I used 'mode' as a 'Merge Rule' ; other Merge Rule options are Frist, Last, Min, Max, Count,  Sum, Mean, StD, Median & Range. When I use 'Mode' it gives the 'land use' type that occurs most of the times in the overlapping area. But, my desired result is to find the land use type that has the most surface area in the overlapping area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Zonal Statistics as Table (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) to accomplish this task. Here is the general workflow:

1. Run [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) using the "Majority" statistic.
2. Join the table with the watershed feature class using [Join Field
   (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000)

---

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Your watershed feature class
watersheds = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb\watersheds'

# Your land cover raster
raster = r'C:\path\to\your\landcover_raster.tif'

# The workspace where the output table will go
zone_table = r'C:\path\to\your\geodatabase.gdb'

# Perform the zonal statistics and output a table
arcpy.sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable (watersheds, 'watershed_id', raster, zone_table, 'DATA', 'MAJORITY')

# Join the table to the watershed feature class by the OBJECTID field (for feature class)
arcpy.JoinField_management(watersheds, 'watershed_id', zone_table, 'OBJECTID', 'MAJORITY')
```